# Overcome duplicate tag constraint with several SelectableSections

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka Forms to build a survey form and have not been able to design my swift properly to overcome the error with duplicate tags.

Many of the questions need only a "Yes/No" type answer and I decided to use the ImageCheckRow selectableValue as found in the Example Project. However I can't figure out how to have two or more List Sections in the same form that re-use the "YES/NO" answer as the code below throws a

> Thread 1: Assertion failed: Duplicate tag userAnswer

My code so far

```
form +++
let userAnswer = ["Yes", "No"] 

SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>("question_one", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true))
    form.last!.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "Are you a registered member?")
    form.last!.tag = "question_one"

    for option in userAnswer {
        form.last! <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(option){ lrow in
                lrow.title = option
                lrow.selectableValue = option
                lrow.value = nil
                lrow.tag = "question_one"
            }
        }

SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>("question_two", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true))
    form.last!.header = HeaderFooterView(title: "Have you managed to do ...")
    form.last!.tag = "question_two"
    for option in userAnswer {
        form.last! <<< ImageCheckRow<String>(option){ lrow in
            lrow.title = option
            lrow.selectableValue = option
            lrow.value = nil
            lrow.tag = "question_two"
        }
    }
```

I tried adding the low.tag based on the answer in this question [Upload Eureka form data to firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804253/upload-eureka-form-data-to-firebase)
 but the problem remains.

Comment: can you post a testable code in github to try help you?

Answer (score 2):

it looks to me you are adding 2 options with the same tag...
shouldn't you use:

```
lrow.tag = "question_one_" + option
```